# Hostname for private endpoints on Autonomous Database?

Tags: hostname, oracle-autonomous-db, private-ip

When we enable private endpoint for Autonomous Database, we use the assigned IP address to connect to the ADB.

Where we can find the hostname to be used internally to resolve the ADB private endpoint to use the name instead of the IP?

Answer (score 0):

Your Autonomous Database with private endpoint's hostname and private IP address will be available on the ADB database UI console.

The hostname can also be viewed and copied from the `tnsnames.ora` in the downloadable wallet zip file.